# Gradle sync failed: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-9.2.1' already disposed: (2s 556ms)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Getting error on Gradle sync

It is failed and showing following error in console output.

> Gradle sync failed: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-9.2.1' already disposed: (2s 556ms)

my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.wordpress"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

And dependencies and its version that is like below:

```
/* IMPORTANT :
 * Be careful when update dependencies, different version library may caused error */

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // google library
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'

    // library for api
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // ripple effect library
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try invalidating the cache and restart

> Goto File >> Invalidate Caches / Restart

also do

> Build >> clean

Answer (score -1):

I figured out this problem by

1. ./gradlew clean
2. Restart Android stduio

**Or you can do this**

- Quit and Restart Android studio. (*Quit not close*)
- Build > Clean your project if needed.

Comment: it took 4 hours to complete Gradle build and arrives tons of error. the whole project crashed.